# A complete metric on the space of bounded Lipschitz function

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete separable metric space.  ($d$ is complete.)  For any bounded Lipschitz function, we define the norm $||\cdot||$.
$$
||f||_1=\sup\left\lbrace\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{d(x,y)}\middle|\,x,y\in X, x \ne y \right\rbrace \\
||f|| = ||f||_\infty+||f||_1 \quad\text{where }||f||_\infty=\sup\{f(x)\mid x \in X\}
$$
I wanted to show that *the space of bounded Lipschitz function under the norm $||\cdot||$ is complete*, but I don't know how to.

My attempt:
Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence dense in $X$.  Let $\epsilon>0$.  Let $(f_n)_n$ be a Cauchy sequence with respect to $||\cdot||$.  Since the sup norm is complete and $||\cdot||_\infty \le ||\cdot||$, we get a uniform convergence $f_n \rightrightarrows f$ under $||\cdot||_\infty$.  There exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that
\begin{align}
& \forall\,m,n\ge N, ||f_m-f_n||_\infty+||f_m-f_n||_1<\epsilon \\
& \forall\,n\ge N, ||f_n-f||_\infty<\epsilon
\end{align}

Since $(f_n)_n$ is Cauchy for the sup norm and for $||\cdot||_1$, it's bounded for those two norms.  As $f_n\rightrightarrows f$, $f$ is also bounded.  There exists $M>0$ so that
\begin{align}
& \forall\,n\in\Bbb{N},\forall x \in X, |f_n(x)|\le M \\
& \forall\, x \in X, |f(x)|\le M \\
& \forall\,n\in\Bbb{N},\forall\, x,y \in X, |f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \le M\,d(x,y)
\end{align}

As I write out the expression for $||f-f_n||_1$, I can do nothing to control the denominator $d(x,y)$.  For any $x,y\in X$ with $x\ne y$,
$$
\frac{|(f-f_n)(x)-(f-f_n)(y)|}{d(x,y)} < \frac{2\epsilon}{d(x,y)}.
$$
I tried finding some $x_*$ and $y_*$ in the dense sequence $(x_n)_n$ so that $d(x,x_*),d(y,y_*)<\epsilon$, but I found this useless as the fraction still appears to be $O(\epsilon)/d(x,y)$.  As $d(x,y)\to 0$, this fraction will explode.  Any help is welcome.

Comment: The quantity $\|\cdot\|_1$ is not a norm.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you explain why?  We have the triangular inequality.  (Fix $x,y$ and it follows from $|\cdot|$ in $\Bbb R$.) If it's zero, then the function inside will map everything to zero.

Comment: It's a seminorm, $\lVert f\rVert_1 = 0$ if $f$ is constant.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. I'll fix it.  The second one $||\cdot||$ should be a norm, so the rest should be unaffected.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to think of $\|f\|_1 = \inf \{ L \ge 0 | \forall x,y, \ |f(x)-f(y)| \le L d(x,y) \}$?

Comment: @copper.hat It should be $\sup$ instead of $\inf$?

Comment: @GNUSupporter: No, the $\sup$ is unbounded. It is equivalent, it just avoids having to fuss with $x,y$ close together.

Comment: @copper.hat I see.  You're taking $L$ over $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $(f_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence, there is an $N$ such that $\lVert f_k - f_m\rVert \leqslant \varepsilon$ for $k,m \geqslant N$. Fixing $m$ and letting $k \to \infty$, it follows that $\lVert f - f_m\rVert_{\infty} \leqslant \varepsilon$ for all $m \geqslant N$. Again fixing $m$, but now also fixing arbitrary $x, y\in X$, and letting $k \to \infty$, it follows that

$$\lvert (f - f_m)(x) - (f - f_m)(y)\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon d(x,y).$$

Since this holds for all $x,y\in X$, it follows that $\lVert f - f_m\rVert_1 \leqslant \varepsilon$. This holds for all $m \geqslant N$. Hence $\lVert f - f_m\rVert \leqslant 2\varepsilon$ for all $m \geqslant N$, so $f_k \to f$ with respect to the norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$.