# is the given space a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $a$, $b$ both are positive real numbers and let $(X,\|.\|_{_{X}})$ be a Banach space. Consider the following spaces:

$C([-a,b],X)=\{f:[-a,b]\to X \mid f\ \text{is continuous}\}$ is a Banach space with respect to the norm
$$\|f\|_{_{C}}=\sup_{[-a,b]}\|f(t)\|_{_{X}}$$
and, $$C_L([0,b],X)=\{g:[0,b]\to X \mid \textrm{there exists a constant } l_{g}>0 \textrm{ such that } \forall t,s\in[0,b],\, \|g(t)-g(s)\|_{_{X}}\leq l_{g} |t-s|\},$$ which is a Banach space with respect to the norm (see [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568419/a-complete-metric-on-the-space-of-bounded-lipschitz-function))
$$\|g\|_{_{L}} = \sup_{[0,b]}\|g(t)\|_{_{X}} + \sup\Big\{\frac{\|g(t)-g(s)\|_{_{X}}}{|t-s|} \ \bigg|\ t,s\in[0,b],\, t\neq s \Big\}.$$

Then is $C([-a,b],X) \cap C_L([0,b],X)$ a Banach space? If so, then what is the norm on the space?

Comment: Are you sure you consider $C([-a, b])$ and $C_L([0, b])$? Their intersection is empty if $a \neq 0$. Also, it usually does not make sense to ask if a space is a Banach space without specifying the norm, as without norm we have only vector structure. Also, note that all functions in $C_L$ are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that $a=0$ because as noted the intersection is empty otherwise, and I denote $X=C([0,b])$ and $Y=C_L([0,b])$. We show that if $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ and $(Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ are Banach spaces then $Z=X\cap Y$ is a Banach space with $\|z\|=\|z\|_X+\|z\|_Y$. I leave it to you to show this is indeed a norm. We show this is a Banach space. Let $\{z_n\}\subset Z$ be a Cauchy sequence. Whence: $$\|z_n-z_m\|=\|z_n-z_m\|_X+\|z_n-z_m\|_Y\geq\max\{\|z_n-z_m\|_Y,\|z_n-z_m\|_X\}$$ hence $z_n$ is Cauchy in both $X$ and $Y$. Let $z_X$ be the limit of $z_n$ in $X$ and $z_Y$ be the limit of $z_n$ in $Y$. Since $\|z\|_Y\geq \|z\|_X$ by definition, $\|z_n-z_Y\|_Y\geq\|z_n-z_Y\|_X\to 0$ and hence $z_X=z_Y$ (notiuce that the righthand side is even defined since we can always talk about the sup norm of bounded functions). So $z=z_X\in C([0,b])\cap C_L([0,b])$ is the desired limit for $\{z_n\}$. Indeed: $$\|z_n-z\|=\|z_n-z\|_X+\|z_n-z\|\to 0$$ So the intersection is a Banach space with the norm given by the sum of norms.

There may be other ways to define a Banach norm on this space, but this is a standard way when the norms are compatible in some sense (this does not! work in general Banach spaces with general norms).